# How to update array based on 2 other arrays, using a functional approach, for a Vue.js search filter?

Tags: javascript, search, vue.js

So, I've been working on this search filter and I'm stuck. I decided to work out the logic first in scratchpad. So e7 has a v-model directive. Also, I'm watching e7, so whenever e7 changes, I'm calling a function.

So, let's say I call rows, It pushes the elements based on e7. My problem is, as the noob that I am, I don't understand how to update the names array. I understand that If I add an element in e7, it calls the watched function, filters the results and updates 'names'. But when I remove and element from e7, how would I update 'names'?

I don't want an easy answer, I just want to know if I'm going in the right direction.

```
    var names = []

    var e7 = ['coop']

    var results = [{'type':'coop','nom':'cercle carre'},
                  {'type':'coop','nom':'cercle rond'},
                  {'type':'hlm','nom':'maison fabre'}
                  ]



    var rows =     results.filter(function(o){
                   return o.type.includes(e7)
                   this.names.push(o.nom)

       })
```

Comment: In Vue, `names` would typically be a computed property derived from `e7` and `results`. You wouldn't use a watch. Vue would automatically update `names` when `e7` or `results` changed.

Comment: @SebastienPaquet Mainly, `this.names.push(o.nom)` will be never fired. Instructions after `return` statement you can consider as lost. Changing instructions order will help, but with your construction, in `names` array you will obtain names from all `result` array objects, not only these with type "coop".

Comment: yeah, I just realized that. That was a mistake. Also, I've been looking into lodash to figure out a way to do what I'm trying to do. And looking at search filter components.